# organized Point Cloud to Depth Image

Tags: opencv, 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have got a fotonic e70 Time-of-Flight camera and like to transfer the point cloud to a depth image. The Point cloud is organized. I thought by simply write each col and row to an cv::Mat with

```
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 160; j++) {
        image.at<short>(i,j) = aImage[j + i * 160 * 4]; //intensity
```

I would resived a rectyfied intensity 2d image. Why is it curved? as you can see here:
[Depth Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMQH7.jpg)

and how do I get a rectify image from a point cloud?

Comment: is this a depth image or an intensity image?!? cuevature probably comes from lens distortion.

Comment: doesn't realy matter, I can write the depth or the intensity as gray value to the cv mat. Both images are curved.

Comment: ok. Probably lens distortion. Is the 3d reconstruction distorted, too?